# nginx subdomain wrong redirect

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have set up a nginx server with this config:

```
server {
        server_name key.mydomain.fun;
        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://mydomain.fun:6969;
        }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.mydomain.fun;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name admin.mydomain.fun;
    ....
}
```

The strange thing is: When starting with a fresh browser and go to "key.mydomain.fun", I get a ssl cert warning that the cert is only valid for "mydomain.fun" and not "key.mydomain.fun". (I have a ssl cert configured for only mydomain.fun, so no wildcard).
After accepting I get to the key-page.

After that I want to access "admin.mydomain.fun" and get the error message again (Thats normal) and after accepting I get to my admin page.

Now the strange thing: when I now want to access "key.mydomain.fun" again, the admin site will be displayed. The URL is still "key.mydomain.fun" but I am at the admin page. After that "key.mydomain.fun" and "admin.mydomain.fun" will get me to the admin page.

When I now reset the browser (delete everything) I can redo those steps and access the "key.mydomain.fun" site again.

What went wrong here? Why do I see the admin page when going to "key.mydomain.fun"?

Comment: You don't have a `server` block for `key.mydomain.fun` using TLS on port 443. The default (first) block is used instead.

Comment: Also, get valid TLS certificates for all your subdomains, it's easy and free with [letsencrypt](https://certbot.eff.org/)

Comment: Ok I did that and now everything is working fine. I also updated to a wildcard certificate. But one question, I only have the cert configured in the `admin.mydomain.fun` server block. Why do I still have a valid cert, or a cert in general, at `key.mydomain.fun`?

Comment: IMHO you did not said to nginx to what `key.domain.fun` should `listen`

Comment: @djdomi Do I need to do that? should I just listen to `listen 80 443` ?

Comment: [Join the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126791/thechat) it will make it easier and we do not spam here